# Only show upcoming event or current events

Tags: query, events

I've been working on this website event page

> http://aishaarab.com/events/

everything is working but I have 2 problems:

1. I can't get it to only show upcoming event meaning when an event is past to not shoe it or not display it.
2. When I output the post_meta onto my page using `<?php meta('event-end-date'); ?>` my result format is 08-12-2014 i would like the month to be letters like this august 12, 2014.

here is code:

```
<ul class="event_list_view">    

<?php // Let's get the data we need to loop through below
//$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$d = date("m-d-Y");
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 hours')); //define "today" format; note timezone offset of -6 hours
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'post_status'  =>  'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'event-start-date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation'  =>   'AND',
    array(
            'key' => 'event-end-date',
         'meta-value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 hours')), //value of "order-date" custom field
         'compare' => '>=', //show events greater than or equal to today
         'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>


<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- pagination here -->

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>





<li class="clearfix">
<div class="featured_tag"></div>


<?php if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<a class="post_img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('event-thumbnail'); ?>
</a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a class="post_img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<img src="http://aishaarab.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/DefaultEvent-125x75.png" alt="" />
</a>
<?php } ?>

<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

<p class="timing"> 
<span>Start Date: </span><?php meta('event-start-date'); ?><br>
<span>End Date: </span><?php meta('event-end-date'); ?><br>
<span>Time: </span><?php meta('event_time'); ?><br>
</p>

<p class="address"><span>Location :</span> <br><?php meta('event_address'); ?>, <?php meta('event_city'); ?>, <?php meta('event_state'); ?>, <?php meta('event_country'); ?></p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p class="bottom">
<a class="read_more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Read More</a>
</p>

</li>


    <!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

     <?php endwhile; else: ?>  
      <p> 
        <?php _e('Sorry, no events matched your criteria.'); ?>  
      </p>  
      <?php endif; ?> <?php //wp_reset_query(); ?>


</ul>
```

Comment: is `event-end-date` meta value contain time in unix time stamp or in formated time string ?

Comment: please share your code for `meta()` function, it's helps us to check that what value you are printing from this function.

Comment: i'm using the more fields plugin and its a text post_meta field used for the event-start-date and event-end-date which is entered as 07-12-2014

Comment: @Ravs i edited the code to this now <?php 
$d = date("m-d-Y");
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
 'post_status'  =>  'publish',
 'meta_key' => 'event-start-date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation'  =>   'AND',
    array(
            'meta_key' => 'event-start-date',
        'value'     =>   time(),
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your are comparing time against wrong time string:

change:

`'meta-value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 hours')), //value of "order-date"`

to this

`'value' => date('m-d-Y', strtotime('-6 hours')), //value of "order-date"`

because your time string is in m-d-Y format and you are check against Y-m-d which is wrong.

**NOTE**

if above trick doesn't work then i suggest you to store time in unix time stamp in database. please read these links for more info how to do it and why

1. https://designhammer.com/blog/sorting-events-date-using-wordpress-custom-post-types
2. http://www.billerickson.net/code/create-a-unix-timestamp-based-on-two-meta-fields/

Comment: updated code per your request but still now working <?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'post_status'  =>  'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'event-start-date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation'  =>   'AND',
    array(
            'key' => 'event-end-date',
         'meta-value' => date('m-d-Y', strtotime('-6 hours')), //value of "order-date"
         'compare' => '>=', //show events greater than or equal to today
         'type' => 'CHAR'
        )
    )
);

Comment: code updated, change `meta-value` to `value` under `meta_query`

Comment: same thing it output all the events but the first event of 2013 is still there but the weird thing i added a future event for 2015 that dont show.

Comment: answer updated, please read link which i mentioned.

Comment: thank you after reading both links, i went into the more fields plugin and instead of using the text field for the date i use the built-in html5 date field and now its working perfectly, thank you